# ASP.NET MVC3 model binder data is invalid when a getter is used against the collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

With this Contact model

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public Phone PrimaryPhone
    {
        get { return Phones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Primary) ?? new Phone(); }
    }
}

public class Phone
{
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Contact contact)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I POST to the HomeController Index using jQuery

```
(function ($) {
        var myData = {
            Name: 'Wesley Crusher',
            Phones: [
                { Primary: false, PhoneNumber: '111-111-1111', Type: 'Business' },
                { Primary: true,  PhoneNumber: '222-222-2222', Type: 'Personal' },
                { Primary: false, PhoneNumber: '333-333-3333', Type: 'Business' }
            ],
            PrimaryPhone: { Primary: true, PhoneNumber: '111-111-1111', Type: 'Business' }
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(myData)
        });
    })(jQuery)
```

**The model binder incorrect builds up the ICollection Phones.** The data is:

- [0] Primary=false, PhoneNumber="111-111-1111", Type="Business"  MVC3ModelBinderJsonTesting.Models.Phone
- [1] Primary=true, PhoneNumber="111-111-1111", Type="Business"   MVC3ModelBinderJsonTesting.Models.Phone
- [2] Primary=false, PhoneNumber="333-333-3333", Type="Business"  MVC3ModelBinderJsonTesting.Models.Phone

**The PhoneNumber "111-111-1111" is repeated and the Type is "Business" instead of "Personal".** Is this expected behavior for some reason or is this a bug?

I can post a sample project if you'd like, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because it's not a primitive. It's a complex object so the model binder tries to set its properties.

Model binding is better suited to binding against "input models" which represent the input coming in from the form. Having calculated properties with business logic on the input model might not be the best approach as you saw.

You could probably have that be an extension method (sadly no support for extension properties) rather than a property of your input model. Or even a proper method. Having it be a property makes the model binder think it's fair game.

If it was a get only primitive type, it wouldn't try to set it.

Comment: While the model binder does think it's fair game, it seems to all work out OK if the PrimaryPhone object being sent matches the data for the primary phone in the Phones array. I don't think the PrimaryPhone property can be changed to a method in this circumstance but that might be another way to fix as well. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3):

I reckon posting the `PrimaryPhone` is causing the problem. Try removing

```
PrimaryPhone: { Primary: true, PhoneNumber: '111-111-1111', Type: 'Business' }
```

As this property has only a getter, and would correctly be determined by the `Primary` property, it should still have valid data.

Comment: Yeah, OP shouldn't be POSTing the PrimaryPhone, since it's a derived property anyway and has no setter.

Comment: This does fix it, but I'd prefer to not have to edit the ajax data. If I or someone else forget to edit the data before sending it to the server and it causes data corruption that is not good.

Comment: @RyanP Why does it matter if I send data for a property that only has a getter, wouldn't you expect the model binder to ignore it since it has no setter?

Comment: Maybe add a setter, which checks for a matching phone number and type, and sets the primary property. If no match (as in the case of the example), add a new item to the collection. (n.b. no idea if this works with the binding.)

Comment: Adding a setter to `Contact.PrimaryPhone` does not seem to fix it. Tried both `set { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("test"); }` and `set { _testPhone = value; }` (I created `_testPhone` as `private Phone _testPhone;`)

Comment: In that case, if you really can't remove the spurious data from the JSON, you may have to create a different class that does the binding, then map accordingly. It might be possible to derive a class from `Contact` and move the PrimaryPhone into it, and bind to the current `Contact` class.